# Sqlite select max query and sorting

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following fields on a SQLite table,

```
  ID - PRODUCT_NAME - PRODUCT_PRICE
  1    WCC9899        1023
  2    WCC9399        9999
  3    WCC93W9        344
  4    WCC9819        55
  5    WCC3333        1023
```

This query returns the **first** item with the highest price:

```
 SELECT max(product_price) as price, product_name, id FROM table
```

But want to get the item with the **highest** price ordered by the **last id**, in this case the result should be:

```
 5    WCC3333        1023
```

Instead i get:

```
 1    WCC9899        1023
```

Order by doesn't works, ty.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
select * 
from your_table
where product_price = (SELECT max(product_price) FROM your_table)
order by id desc
limit 1
```